# How to not allow to switch between word instances if any modal window is opened using vsto?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vsto, word-addins

I have created a word addin using VSTO in vs2010 and it is working fine. But i am faceing a handicap issue, If I open my Windows modal dialog in word then it should not allow to switch between multiple instances of word.

I want same behavior of my modal dialog as showdialog/openfiledialog in MS Word.

I already have modal dialog by setting owner property with win handle in wpf or via showdialog(hwnd).

but still i am able to switch between word documents.

thanks in advance.
sumit sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ShowDialog method of the Form class and specify the parent window handle using the IWin32Window interface. The Window class from the Word object model provides the [Hwnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj231484(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns an integer that indicates the window handle of the specified window. You can use it to create an instance of the IWin32Window interface and pass it to the ShowDialog method.